# TableRow won't scroll horizontally

Tags: android, tablerow

I needed a Horizontal ListView and was advised to use TableRow instead. Now, I have problem. The TableRow simply won't scroll horizontally. How to solve this issue?

Comment: you can use Horizontal ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap the `TableView` into a `HorizontalScrollView`. Something like this:

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <TableView
        android:id="@+id/your_tv"
        ...>
    </TableView>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

---- EDIT ----

To know which `View` have you clicked, as you know you have the tag and that when you fire an `onClick()` event you'll get the `View` that fired it by parameter, you can use something like this:

```
your_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("TagDebug", "Hey, I'm the child number " + v.getTag().toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work, NKN. It just makes vertical listview

Comment: Sorry, I had put a `ListView` instead of a `TableView`. Now I updated that code, though I suppose you already try that.

Comment: So I tried again and the only thing i get when I place a couple of textviews inside tablerow is a multi-line text :S

Comment: What is the `HorizontalScrollView`'s parent `layout_width` parameter set to? (should be `wrap_content`)

Comment: You sir made my day! Works :)

Comment: Excuse me, one more thing. I made this and now I wanted to make all the items I added clickable. I inflate Views and add them one by one. They are added and scrollable. When I store them, I also remember their ids. When I set onClickListener, it implements method onClick which has View as a parameter. I compare that View's id to the stored id's , but always get the same item-first one. What to do?

Comment: Depends on how you're setting your IDs. However, if your commitment is having a functionality in the `onClickListener()`, I'd recommend using `setTag()` as the identificating element instead of `id`s. As you're defining your id inside a `Layout`, they'll be capable of being `findViewById()` just inside that `Layout`, so keep this in mind (basically, you'll have to do: `parent.getViewById(your_id)`). However, I'd still bet for the tag instead.

Comment: So I figured out that I actually put an onClickListener on a tablerow, that's why I get the ID of a row probably. How to access separate elements? Cuz whichever I click of those, I get ID of a tablerow. I even tried setId() on all views before I add them. Here is my code: [link](http://paste2.org/JaZ8sn0L) . Can you post some code or smth?

Comment: You're on the right way, simply call `.setTag(i)` instead of `.setId(i)`. You may call afterwards the following: your_table_view.findViewWithTag(4)`, for instance to recover a `View`.

Comment: It's true. And I can recover child of my TableRow with findViewWithTag. But, how can I find which particular child it is? I can't compare it to any. When I click one of them, I need to get the position of exactly that child. That's what confuses me. Thanks for answering me whole day man, I know I'm tiring :D

Comment: You could simply set the position as tag (as you may be doing now), and then get your `View` simply calling `your_tablerow.getChild(i)`: This will give you back that child. However, `findViewWithTag()` will do the same, since it return a `View`, and with the tag you may know which child is it.

Comment: How can I know an "i" for getChild(), when I get the whole View of a TableRow as an argument for onClick() (or do I?) ? I need that exact child(that i). Can't explain better :(

Comment: If you use a counter starting in `0` (something like `int count = 0`), and each time you add a `View` increment that count using `count++`, you'll have an unique identifier for each view. Simply assign that `count` as the `tag` of each `View` and it'll make them unique, this way, you can do both operations: find them by tag and given a view, know which child is it, just take care of updating the tags if you delete some row so they keep sequential.

Comment: I understand all this and I already did this. But I can't figure out how to retrieve element. I have nothing to compare it to.
So here is what I have:
- Added tags to each View before adding it to row.
- Added ids.
- Now when I click, I get row View. I can retrieve all of them by either tag or ID, but how to know which one is the one I clicked? Cant compare to nothing. Can u give code?

Comment: I think I finally understood what you're asking for - I modified the answer, check if that's what you wanted.

Comment: java.NullPointerException is what I get. That's because View v contains the whole TableRow(as I suppose), not a single element inside it(its child). And I didn't put a tag for the row. And I tested finally by putting a tag for the row and I got it. It was the number 15 which I put for the row, whichever item I clicked. Maybe there is no way to get the position of the item inside this crap? :( Hope there is

Comment: This approach assumes that you put a tag to **each** `View` you have inside the `TableRow`! The way you're doing it indeed makes impossible to know which child was it. Everytime you define a `View` to add to the `TableRow`, set the tag **and** define a `onClickListener` on it, I think it's the only way.

Comment: Finally did it! I set each View clickable, then my class implements OnClickListener, and I added that global method. So when I click any View, inside that global method I get it's tag, and then that's the position! Thanks so much for endless help, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Share some of your code so we can at least know what you tried.

AFAIK if you put TableRow in a ScrollView, it works. This is what I did while working on simple table;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="false" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerPadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/p1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/p2"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/p3"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/p4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/p4"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newScore2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newScore3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newScore4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/addScore" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And you can add row to table like this;

```
tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);    
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);
        TextView textView4 = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(score + "");
        textView2.setText(score2 + "");
        textView3.setText(score3 + "");
        textView4.setText(score4 + "");
        row.addView(textView);
        row.addView(textView2);
        row.addView(textView3);
        row.addView(textView4);
        tl.addView(row);
```

Comment: It works. I just used this for my simple table app. Posted full xml now